# JAXB Marshall String to base64

Tags: java, jaxb

I need to marshall an object which includes a String variable.
The String var. contains an XML document, and it gets marshalled with escaping to XMLElement.

I'd like to marshall the String variable to base64 format, and back to String on unmarshall.

Is this posiible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an `XmlAdapter` to convert the `String` to/from a `byte[]` during the marshalling/unmarshalling process.  By default JAXB will represent a `byte[]` as `base64Binary`.

**XmlAdapter (Base64Adapter)**

Below is an `XmlAdapter` that will convert between a `String` and a `byte[]`.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class Base64Adapter extends XmlAdapter<byte[], String> {

    @Override
    public String unmarshal(byte[] v) throws Exception {
        return new String(v);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] marshal(String v) throws Exception {
        return v.getBytes();
    }

}
```

**Java Model (Foo)**

The `XmlAdapter` is configured using the `@XmlJavaTypeAdapter` annotation.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlRootElement
public class Foo {

    private String bar;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(Base64Adapter.class)
    public String getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public void setBar(String bar) {
        this.bar = bar;
    }

}
```

**Demo**

In the demo code below we will create an instance of `Foo` and marshal it to XML.

```
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setBar("<abc>Hello World</abc>");

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(foo, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Below is the output from running the demo code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<foo>
    <bar>PGFiYz5IZWxsbyBXb3JsZDwvYWJjPg==</bar>
</foo>
```

Comment: This is correct, but, for those that this example didn't work, you have to check the version of the `jaxb-impl` since the version `2.1.13` has a bug. Simply by changing the version to `2.1.17` make it work.

Comment: is there a way to do it without adding annotations, and just modifying marshaller (in case of SOAP where the class is being (re)generated form external wsdl)